# Codeigniter: decrypt password

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I am transferring a client's program that was coded with Codeigniter by another developer. I tried searching through stackoverflow for my answer, but I know nothing about developing programs or Codeigniter so I'm not able to understand the answers.

The client's login credentials are not working, but they were working on their previous website. I went into the database to see if the credentials matched but the passwords were obviously encrypted.

I have located the key. Now I want to decrypy them. I found that I need to use this code (not my encrypted string):

```
$encrypted_string = 'APANtByIGI1BpVXZTJgcsAG8GZl8pdwwa84';
$plaintext_string = $this->encrypt->decode($encrypted_string);
```

but I have no clue how to implement this code.

Comment: This may help: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html

Comment: Thanks, Rocket. I did find that document; that's where I found the code I referenced in my question.

Comment: Are their passwords *actually* encrypted?  There should **never** be a way to retrieve the user's original password.  That's why you *hash* passwords.  Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php (these work in PHP 5.5+, if you have a lower version try https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: I don't know the difference. There is a column titled "varpassword" which looks similar to the encrypted_string above. Also, I don't see any references to hash in the code.

Comment: You'll need to look at their original code or ask their developers.  Just looking at the fields in the database won't help you.  If it is encrypted, then you'll need a *key* to decrypt.  I'm going to assume (or rather hope) it's hashed, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, asking their developers isn't an option :( I have the encryption key already and the code needed to decrypt what is in the database. I just need to know how to implement the code.

Comment: At it's most basic, *encryption* is reversible, a *hash* is not.

Comment: Well, if you have the key, then just do `$this->encrypt->decode($msg, $key);` (or set `$config['encryption_key']`).  What *exactly* are you having trouble with?

Comment: Did you follow the steps in that link? Did you skip this: `$config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY";` or use the method @RocketHazmat suggested.

Comment: My trouble is that I don't know how to DO that code. I'm guessing that once I put that code somewhere (where?), it will display the decrypted string? Or will it decrypt it in the database? Again, my problem is implementing that code. Which file? Where can I retrieve the decrypted string?

Comment: Straight form that document "To save your key to your application/config/config.php, open the file and set `$config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY";`"

Comment: config.php already has that line. Where do I implement the code they reference in that document? The one under the heading "$this->encrypt->decode()"

Comment: @Tara: You put this code in a PHP file, a controler possibly.  The database isn't decrypting it, PHP is.  If you want to *display* the decrypted string, then just `echo` it or whatever.  You do know how to use the CodeIgniter framework (and MVC), right?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but as I stated in my question, I know nothing about Codeigniter. I have solved a few other problems that were in this program by using the user guide, but am stuck at this one. I will echo that code and see what happens. Edited to add: turning this project away due to my inexperience is not an option, unfortunately. I appreciate all of your guyses help though.

Comment: @Tara: Sorry, I guess I missed that part.  You can put this code after where it gets the password from the database.  For *debugging*, you can put it in the model, or in the controller after it calls the model (and the model returns a value).

Comment: Thanks, Rocket. I'll try that now.